# Hibernate Default Schema not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to set a default schema in my Hibernate mapping, like so:

```
<persistence-unit name="store">

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jar-file>store-data-0.0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar-file>

    <properties>
        <property
            name="hibernate.show_sql"
            value="true" />
        <property
            name="hibernate.format_sql"
            value="true" />
        <property
            name="hibernate.default_schema"
            value="Store"></property>
        <property
            name="hibernate.archive.autodetection"
            value="class" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

However, when I run a simple test query:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager manager;

@Transactional
public List<Person> listPeople() {
    return manager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p", Person.class).getResultList();
}
```

I get this:

Invalid object name 'Person'.

When I run a native query:

```
manager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Store.Person", Person.class).getResultList();
```

Everything works fine.

I'm running a SE application, using Spring. I have used the `hibernate.default_schema` in a Web App before, and it worked just fine.

This is how I declare the entities mapping:

```
<bean
    id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property
        name="dataSource"
        ref="mysqlDataSource" />
    <property
        name="packagesToScan"
        value="com.base.package" /> <!-- base package for all my entities -->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How and where do you declare the mapping for the class-entity `Person` ?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the entity mapping. Also, I think is worth mentioning that everything works fine if I create my tables in the base (dbo) schema.

Comment: Is it possible that the default schema should be "dbo.Store" instead of "Store" ? or some other explicit owner of the "Store" schema? Note that "dbo" is a schema owner, not a schema. See http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-the-difference-between-owners-and-schemas-in-sql-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could solve the problem by setting the default schema directly in my Spring context file:

```
<bean
    id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property
        name="dataSource"
        ref="mysqlDataSource" />
    <property
        name="packagesToScan"
        value="com.base.package" /> <!-- base package for all my entities -->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">Store</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```