# Adding Schema name to entity in Spring data?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, entity-framework, spring-data

I am getting an error when using an `Oracle DB` and `Spring Data`. The error is:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The cause of this error is that the user I am connecting with **does not** have access to the tables in the schemas I wish to connect to.

I read that 2 fixes to this are to create `synonyms` in my database or to specify the `schema` that each entity/table belongs to.

I am going to try the Schema approach first. How do I do so?

My **example entity** below, a *Dog* in the *Vet* Schema:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Dog")
public class Dog
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Owner")
    private String owner;

  //getters and setters etc...
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `@Table` annotation provides the `schema` attribute:

```
@Table(name = "Dog", schema = "Vet")
```

Comment: Is this the same as the other answer above, the SCHEMA.Table method? Which one would be preferable?

Comment: @java123999 Not sure if the result is the same. But this is what the docs says. [Java Doc table](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Table.html). In my projects I used it like this.

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible specify the schema once in a properties file for all entites. E.g: hibernate.vets.default_schema=VET ?

Comment: If all your entites in your project needs this schema. Think about to change the permission of your oracle user. Just give the user the permission on that schema and you dont need to use schema in the annotation at all.

Comment: Thanks I may do that, but the hibernate.vets.default_schema=VET  way of doing things is the same as specifying the schema for each entity individually?

Comment: @java123999 yes there are many ways to do it. For example in the `spring context` shown here [example 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846636/hibernate-default-schema-not-working) or when you use spring boot its more easier [example 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278659/change-database-schema-used-by-spring-boot) or here another [example3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737420/how-to-set-up-default-schema-name-in-jpa-configuration)

Comment: This solution is not working for me but  @j.chomel 's answer is worked for me. It is weird:(

Comment: Is there any way to set schema dynamically ?

Answer (score 8):

You must prefix your tables with the schema name and with a `.` inbetween them:

```
@Table(name = "VET.Dog")
```

Comment: Because this is how you reference tables on a given schema in Oracle.

Comment: is this preferable over the @Table(name = "Dog", schema = "Vet") way of doing this?

Comment: No, it is not better than the other. It is rather a DBA point of view (mine).

Comment: This may not work when using the default naming strategy. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52974114/4719208) has a workaround so hibernate won't try to sanitize the table name by replacing dots with underscores, but I found the proposed solution also stops replacing camelCase with snake_case.