# Specify new schema at entity level in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here are my spring data jpa properties at connection configuration level in application.properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host:3306/schema1?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

All entities by default look for tables in **schema1** However, I have another **schema2** present at the same host for which I want an entity to map to

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1",schema = "schema2")
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    //some columns
}
```

I have defined a repository for this entity as follows:

```
    @Repository
     public interface Entity1Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity1, Long> {

    //some methods

}
```

However jpa is still looking for `table1` in `schema1` despite it being clearly annotated as schema2 at the `@Table` annotation in the entity level.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Which `@Table` annotation are you using? Some pro-tips, the `@Repository` doesn't add anything, remove it. Using `@Data` for entities (as well as `@ToString`) is a bad idea as it generates a wrong `equals`/`hashCode` for entities.

Comment: javax.persistence.table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552556/hibernate-5-ignores-table-schema-param (might be relevant). Try `catalog` instead of `schema`.

Comment: That worked thanks. Can you repost that as an answer so that I may accept it? @M.Deinum

Comment: I'm going to mark this as a duplicate of the other one.