# How can I access the data from a table in another schema

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to get data from a table in another schema, which I do have grant permission.

Tried select query from my current database. I am able to acess the table in other schema(**USERAUTH**)

Entity had created with schema attribute

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PESRSON",  schema=USERAUTH)
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="CODE")
    private Long code;

    @Column(name="TITLE")
    private String  title;

    .....
    .....
    .....

}
```

Created Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {


}
```

In service, to get the record.

```
@Autowired
private PersonRepo personRepo;
.....
.....
.....

Person per = personRepo.getOne(663L);
```

Exception on server start.

```
ERROR ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

How can I access the data from a table in another schema.

Comment: Did you can connect to your desired database ?

Comment: Yes i can connect.

Comment: I think you need to configure `spring-data-jpa` for multiple datasources. A great example can be found here. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Schema name to entity in Spring data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355358/adding-schema-name-to-entity-in-spring-data)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and after doing a bit of Google I find out below two options. You can use either way to achieve the same.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PESRSON",  schema="USERAUTH", catalog="USERAUTH")
public class Person implements Serializable { }
```

or

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERAUTH.PESRSON")
public class Person implements Serializable { }
```