# Spring: map entity to a scheme

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Im trying to create a Spring-Boot Data JPA-Application with Entities based in multiple schemes using an oracle Database.s
I have two Schemes, `scheme_a` and `scheme_b`. The DDL User for `scheme_a` is `scheme_a`, the DDL user for `scheme_b` is `scheme_b`. Both DDL user will be used by liquibase to create my initial table structure.

My application has two entities:

- Entity `foo` is managed by my application and should be based in scheme `scheme_a`.
- Entity `bar` is managed by a third party library and should be based in scheme `scheme_b`.

My application has a user `app_user`, with CRUD-rights on all tables and sequences located in `scheme_a` and `scheme_b`. This user is my DMA-user

My plan was to use Spring-Data-Jpa to connect with the database using the `app-user` user. This user should be able to work with all entities in `scheme_a` and `scheme_b`.

**Example of Entity `foo` (`bar` has identical structure):**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_FOO")
public class FooEntity {

public FooEntity () { // no-args c-tor for hibernate
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "foo_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_foo_id", sequenceName = "sequence_foo_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence_foo_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "foo_name")
    private String name;
}
```

**Every entity has its own `Repository`:**

```java
public interface FooRepo extends CrudRepository<FooEntity, Long> {

...

}
```

**My configuration:**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {FooRepo.class, BARRepo.class})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {FooEntity.class, BarEntity.class})
public class AppDBConfig {

...

}
```

But every time my application tries to start it is not able to locate the table `T_FOO` based in `scheme_a`.

I am not able to extend the `@Table`-Annotation with corresponding scheme. Does any one know a way to solve this problem? Is it possible to create something like a "scheme-table" to tell hibernate in which scheme which entity is located, like

```
var schemeMap = new HashMap<Class, String>();
schemeMap.put(FooEntity.class, scheme_a);
schemeMap.put(BarEntity.class, scheme_b);
```

Greetings from Germany!

Comment: It is not clear what you mean under `I am not able to extend the @Table-Annotation with corresponding scheme.`, but you can set schema via `@Table(name = "T_FOO", schema="scheme_a")` or globally by setting `hibernate.default_schema` property. See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-global-catalog-schema).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Schema name to entity in Spring data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355358/adding-schema-name-to-entity-in-spring-data)

Comment: My Problem is that `BarEntity` is managed by an company internal third-party-library. I am not able to add the scheme to the annotation because the source code is not available for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the schema in the `@Table` annotation.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_FOO", schema = "scheme_a")
public static void FooEntity {
// ..
```

Since you don't seem to be allowed to change the annotation on `FooEntity` I see a couple of options available to you:

If you can change the annotation on `BarEntity` but not on `FooEntity` you can make the schema of `FooEntity` your default schema and set the schema for `BarEntity` in the annotation.

If you can't change either entity but have some control over the database you can create a view or synonym in your main schema that mirrors `T_FOO`.

You can also configure Hibernate with XML and specify the schema there.

You could decompile the class file containing `FooEntity`, add the required annotation and compile it again.

You probably could use ByteBuddy or a similar tool to do that at runtime during startup of your application.

Comment: My Problem is that `BarEntity` is managed by an company internal third-party-library. I am not able to add the scheme to the annotation because the source code is not available for me.
Therefore i am looking for a way without adding the scheme to the annotation

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I updated the question to include some options for this scenario.